# Databricks failed to sync with DevOps due to authorization code or refresh token expiry

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

I am trying to sync azureDevops git with Azure Databricks but getting the below error:

> Error while syncing Git history: {"error_description":"AADSTS70008: The provided authorization code or refresh token has expired due to inactivity. Send a new interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 6270fe6e-57b4-4265-ba77-83c5a6d55800\r\nCorrelation ID: 12a0a5a6-2ec8-4be4-a2c8-d18677d46f9d\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-14 12:25:05Z","error":"invalid_grant","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=70008"}

Can someone please advise how to resolve this?

I have generated a new token as well by going into User Settings, thought it might work but still getting this error

Comment: just read that Azure DevOps Services requires no extra authentication, so there is no sense of creating a new token, so how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try unlinking and linking azure devops repo again?

Comment: @NJ1 This error seems an issue with the auth token and seems it is expired. In such cases we have to log out and log in to make sure that we refresh the token.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT - yes, you are correct, logged out completely from Azure portal and logged in again, with MFA...it worked now.. thank you so much!!

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT - yes I did this but it didnt work, but post log off and log in back again, I was able to link the repo and databricks, thank you...

Comment: @NJ1 Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems an issue with the auth token and seems it is expired. In such cases we have to log out and log in to make sure that we refresh the token.